# C# SAP ABAP query TABLE STRUCTURE

Tags: c#, abap, saprfc

I have the following structure received from SAP software, what is the correct way to obtain the `DATA` field where the `TBL_ACT` field is equal to "TAR - ENTRY"?

*Code used in the API:*

```
public HttpResponseMessage RFC_GETEND([FromBody] SapModel model)
{
     RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(model.Ip);
     RfcRepository r= dest.Repository;
     IRfcFunction f = r.CreateFunction("ZUBGP_RFC_019");
     f.Invoke(dest);
     return new HttpResponseMessage() { 
         Content = new StringContent(f[0].GetValue().ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain") 
     };
}
```

*Structure received from SAP software:*

```
TABLE  
[STRUCTURE ZUBGPMS019 { FIELD TBL_ACT=VIM - OUT DATA=2019-09-03 }]
[STRUCTURE ZUBGPMS019 { FIELD TBL_ACT=TAR - ENTRY FIELD DATA=2021-10-01 }] 
[STRUCTURE ZUBGPMS019 { FIELD TBL_ACT=TAR - OUT FIELD DATA=2022-12-31 }] 
[STRUCTURE ZUBGPMS019 { FIELD TBL_ACT=SEC - OUT DATA=2019-06-01 }]
```

Comment: Use a JSON deserializer.

Comment: If you are using SAP .Net Connector, please add the corresponding tag. You are talking about a home-made function (`ZUBGP_RFC_019`) that nobody knows, so please indicate what is the exact type of `DATA`. Please also indicate what you have tried so far.

Comment: @jdweng Are you sure? The second code block in the question doesn't look like valid JSON to me.

Comment: Square brackets hold arrays.  Each row of Table would be an array of one.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp